# Jquery DataTable - adding multiple total rows

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is my code where I successfully add totals row representing sums by desired columns to the end of my dataTable.

```
$('#user-table1').DataTable({
  "footerCallback": function (nRow, aasData, iStart, iEnd, aiDisplay ) {                   
    $($(nRow).children()).remove();                            
    for(var i=0;i<aasData[0].length;i++){                       
      var a= document.createElement('td');                   
      $(a).html('');                                         
      $(nRow).append(a);                                     
    }                                                          
    var columns=[4, 5,6,7, 8, 9]; //the columns you wish to add             

    $($(nRow).children().get(0)).html("Сумма");
    for(var j in columns) {                                   
      var columnActual= columns[j];                        
      var total=0;                                           
      for(var i=iStart;i<iEnd;i++){                           
        total=total+parseInt(aasData[aiDisplay[i]][columnActual]);
      }                                                              
      $($(nRow).children().get(columnActual)).html(total);
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any way to add multiple total rows (like min, max, average, stddev etc) in addition to sum totals ?

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this? It will easier for us to help you..

Comment: @MoshFeu, I am not familiar with the concepts of bins and snippets. Can you clarify please ?

Comment: Please read this article https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/. The [bin](http://jsbin.com/)